# Python on Android subprocess: /bin/sh: ls: not found

Tags: android, python, shell, subprocess, popen

As I'm running an old Python version on android which gives incorrect file sizes for files > 4 GB I tried writing a workaround to get the correct sizes, code:

```
def getsize_workaround( filename ):
import subprocess as s
output = s.Popen("ls -l " + filename, shell=True, executable="/system/bin/sh", stdout=s.PIPE).communicate()[0]
size = long(re.split(r'\s+', output)[3])
return size
```

This works well when I try to call it using a simple python script:

> print(getsize_workaround(path))

However, when I try to use it in my NZBGet VideoSort script it can't find ls and pops this error at: `output = s.Popen("ls -l " + filename, shell=True, executable="/system/bin/sh", stdout=s.PIPE).communicate()[0]`->  : /bin/sh: ls: not found. (function is called at line 824, see dropbox link below).

Haven't got a clue why it can't find ls anymore, anyone help is much appreciated. You can find the VideoSort script here: https://db.tt/oM3U5gZR.

Comment: I don't know what NZBGet VideoSort is, but my guess is that either it's running with a non-standard `PATH` or running inside a very limited chroot jail or similar, and therefore `ls` isn't on the path. Try printing out `os.environ['PATH']`, or `subprocess`ing `'echo $PATH', shell=True`, and maybe loop through the resulting paths and `listdir`ing each one to see what's there.

Comment: Also, it's very weird that you're getting an error from `/bin/sh` when you explicitly asked for `/system/bin/sh`. With `shell=True` (except on Windows), `executable` should replace your default.

Comment: Finally, why are you using `shell=True` in the first place? Unless your Android device has no real `ls` command and you need to run it out of BusyBox, it's both simpler and better to just use `['ls', '-l', filename], stdout=s.PIPE` and leave the shell out of it. (If you do need to run it out of BusyBox, then maybe the `/bin/sh` vs. `/system/bin/sh` is the problem?)

Comment: NZBGet is a program to download using nzb's file which can call a post processing script to process the recently downloaded files, in my case this script is VideoSort.py.

I was using the list instead of the shell=True at first, but changed it because it wasn't working and trying to figure out why. Found out path was incorrectly set by printing it when the script was run from NZBGet, not sure why. Managed to fix it by setting os.environ['PATH'] to include /system/bin, /system/xbin.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PATH variable didn't include the correct directories when run from NZBGet. Fixed by setting os.environ['PATH'] manually. Thanks to abernert for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

also try adding an alias in your bash script for the python version you want to use

`alias python=<python version you want to use>`